# input shape in LSTM-CNN model

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

How can I give this data to LSTM-CNN model as an input shape?

I put my own model code. My data is a satellite image.

```
print(train_x.shape,train_y.shape,test_x.shape,test_y.shape)

(9219, 7, 7, 12) (9219,) (3951, 7, 7, 12) (3951,)
```

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, 4, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape= (-----)))
model.add(LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 8, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Conv1D(16, 8, activation="relu", padding='same'))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: If you want to use `Conv1D`, you need to `.reshape` your 4D input data to 3D and use it's shape like `input_data=(data_3d.shape[-2], data_3d.shape[-1])`. To reshape, `data_4d.reshape(data_4d.shape[0], -1, data_4d.shape[-1])`

Comment: I did this and my model ran correctly, but now my problem is in the model.fit function. And this part of my code is not executed. and it gives me the following error
    ' ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 7, 12), found shape=(None, 7, 7, 12)'

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.